# Why does ctype_space in PHP return "true" for some numeric values?

Tags: php

I was recently playing with the `ctype_*` group of functions in PHP and found strange behaviour. For example, I have some code:

```
    for ( $i = 0; $i < 1000000; $i++ ) {
        if ( ctype_space( $i ) ) {
            var_dump( $i );
        }
    }
```

When `$i` has the values *[9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 32]* then `[ctype_space][1]` will return **true**. I am using the next PHP version:

```
   PHP 7.1.4-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+1 (cli) (built: Apr 11 2017 22:12:32) ( NTS )
   Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
   Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
      with Zend OPcache v7.1.4-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies
      with Xdebug v2.5.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2017, by Derick Rethans
```

Is this a bug or a feature of PHP? Maybe I don't know something? Please, help me to understand it.

Comment: To quote the manual: *"Note: If an integer between -128 and 255 inclusive is provided, it is interpreted as the ASCII value of a single character (negative values have 256 added in order to allow characters in the Extended ASCII range). Any other integer is interpreted as a string containing the decimal digits of the integer."* ... 9 is TAB, 10 is LF ... and so on.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-space.php):

> If an integer between -128 and 255 inclusive is provided, it is interpreted as the ASCII value of a single character (negative values have 256 added in order to allow characters in the Extended ASCII range). Any other integer is interpreted as a string containing the decimal digits of the integer.

In ASCII those numbers are whitespace characters:

```
 9 Horizontal tab
10 New Line
11 Vertical Tab
12 Form feed
13 Carriage return
32 Space
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation

Answer (score 3):

You've actually linked to documentation containing the answer.

> If an integer between -128 and 255 inclusive is provided, it is interpreted as the ASCII value of a single character (negative values have 256 added in order to allow characters in the Extended ASCII range). Any other integer is interpreted as a string containing the decimal digits of the integer.